# How to access http screen stream on ps4

Tags: ps4, android

I have been messing around with trying to cast my phone screen to my ps4, I have been using an HTTP stream to try but the ps4 when I go to try to access local IP address it tells me unsupported media no matter what I'm hosting in the browser. Does anyone know a way to get around this?  I was thinking a possibility would be a html5 vnc player but I can't figure out how to get it to access local IP streams. Any ideas helps.

(trying to cast n64 on my phone so we can do ssb multiplayer with an decent screen)

Comment: What do you type on the PS4 browser ?

Comment: With using http stream the local ip to access is something to the effect of 192.168.1.3:8080.

Comment: Try streaming on youtube etc and watching in app? there'll be delay but it's better than nothing.

Comment: That's the issue though.  The delay would probably make it unplayable

Comment: To play a game I would need <500ms delay

Comment: Better suggestion: if you want to play android games on a big screen, get an android box.